# How to change the website Tab name in Dash-Plotly using python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I Want to change the name and icon which are displayed on the webpage tab which is developed using Dash-Plotly with python.

[image: Tab]

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://community.plotly.com/t/including-page-titles-favicon-etc-in-dash-app/4648

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.title = 'This is my App'
app._favicon = ("path_to_folder/your_icon.ico")
.....
.....
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: is there a specific size for the ICO file bc when i add the my image it doesn't show up

Comment: try [16 x 16] pixels. Favicon is supposed to be a set of 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48 pictures in ICO format. Non-Square pictures are not allowed.

Comment: After change the size of icon, my icon isn't loaded correctly (I change the file type form .png to .ico).

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem, solved with favicon resolution 48x48 pixels, and folder name 'assets':

```
from dash import Dash
import os

app = Dash(__name__)
app.title = 'Your title'
app._favicon = (os.path.join('assets', 'your_icon.ico'))
```